# ActionMailer sent with body unavailable in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, null

So ive got a ActionMailer mailer

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def notify_doctor_of_updated_document(document)
    recipients  document.user.email_id
    from        "(removed for privacy)"
    subject     "Document #{document.document_number} has been updated and saved as #{document.status}"
    sent_on     Time.now
    body        :document => document
  end
end
```

and the view is

```
Document
<%= @document.class %>
```

but when running

```
>> d = Document.last
=> #<Document id: "fff52d70-7ba2-11de-9b70-001ec9e252ed", document_number: "ABCD1234", procedures_count: 0, user_id: "630", created_at: "2009-07-28 18:18:07", updated_at: "2009-08-30 20:59:41", active: false, facility_id: 94157, status: "incomplete", staff_id: nil, transcriptionist_id: nil, job_length: nil, work_type: nil, transcription_date: nil, non_trans_edit_date: nil, pervasync_flag: true, old_id: nil>
>> ReportMailer.deliver_notify_doctor_of_updated_document(d)
=> #<TMail::Mail port=#<TMail::StringPort:id=0x8185326c> bodyport=#<TMail::StringPort:id=0x8184d6b4>>
```

from the console this is printed in the log

```
Sent mail to (removed for privacy)

Date: Tue, 11 May 2010 20:45:14 -0500
From: (removed for privacy)
To: (removed for privacy)
Subject: Document ABCD1234 has been updated and saved as incomplete
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=mimepart_4bea082ab4ae8_aa4800b81ac13f5


--mimepart_4bea082ab4ae8_aa4800b81ac13f5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

Document
NilClass=

--mimepart_4bea082ab4ae8_aa4800b81ac13f5--
```

Comment: Are you sure the spelling of "`:document`" (the key in the `body` Hash) and "`@document`" (the instance variable in the view) match? Are you sure the view you provided is in `app/views/report/notify_doctor_of_updated_document.erb`? Clearly it's not `nil` inside the mailer action; if it were, `document.user.email_id` would blow up.

Comment: Yeah I've checked the spelling a few times just to be sure and its generating the email right so I know the paths are right its just that for some reason using the "body :document => document" isn't setting the variable for the view.

Answer (score 1):

Please could you show your controller actions. One of my example in my recent application is this.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base  
  # Submission email
  def submission_batch(batch)
    recipients  batch.user.email
    from        "webmaster@gmail.com"
    subject     "Thank you for submitting a batch"
    body        :batch => batch
  end 
end
```

The controller action/method is

```
def update_samp
    @batch = Batch.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
       if @batch.update_attributes(params[:batch])
         UserMailer.deliver_submission_batch(@batch)
         flash[:success] = 'Batch and Sample details were successfully stored and an automated email briefing the details have been sent to your email. '
         format.html { redirect_to(@batch) }         
         format.xml  { head :ok }
       else
         format.html { render :action => "sample_production" }
         format.xml  { render :xml => @batch.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
  end
```

And then my View is as follows

```
Hi <%= @batch.user.name %>
 and further you describe the email
```

Now there are things which I would like to mention to check.

1. Check your smtp settings. I use Gmail for sending mails. I have my settings set up in the development and production environment.
2. Check the names/spellings of the variables you send.
3. Make sure the html.erb file is the same name as the method defined in the user_mailer.rb

Hope these things help.

Cheers